# How can I debug why an ObservedObject is no longer receiving a Published variable change?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

After implementing a new feature within my application, I was getting reports that my search bar was no longer functioning properly. Upon debugging further, I narrowed it down to the `ObservedObject` not receiving the changes from my `Published` variable.

The debug statements within the `LocationHandler` class print out and I can place a breakpoint in different locations to obtain the `@Published` variables print outs however, when I put a breakpoint on the `UIViewRepresentable` where I am using my `ObservedObject`, `locationHandler.lhLatitude` is printing `0.0` and I'm not sure why that would be the case. I would love to continue to debug this further however, I am unsure how to move forward for such.

```swift
class LocationHandler: ObservableObject {
    @Published var lhLatitude: Double
    @Published var lhLongitude: Double

    internal init(lhLatitude: Double, lhLongitude: Double) {
        self.lhLatitude = lhLatitude
        self.lhLongitude = lhLatitude
    }
    
    func changeRegion(searchArea: String) {
        let searchRequest = MKLocalSearch.Request()
        searchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = searchArea
        
        let search = MKLocalSearch(request: searchRequest)
        search.start { (response, error) in
            guard let response = response else {
                // MARK: Consider an alert here or some sort of thing notice rather then having no resposne?
                return
            }
            
            let freshLocation = response.mapItems.first?.placemark.coordinate
            self.lhLatitude = freshLocation!.latitude
            self.lhLongitude = freshLocation!.longitude
            
            // MARK: Debugging.
            if (freshLocation!.latitude > 0.0) {
                print("Fresh Latitude: \(self.lhLatitude)")
                print("Fresh Longitude: \(self.lhLongitude)")
            }
        }
    } // End of changeRegion function.
}
```

```swift
// This is on a UIViewRepresentable.

    @ObservedObject var locationHandler: LocationHandler

// This is located in the updateView function and this is it's use-case, I've yet to have an issue with it until this immediate instance.
       if locationHandler.lhLongitude > (0.0) {
            print("Location Handler Latitude : \(locationHandler.lhLatitude)")
            view.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: locationHandler.lhLatitude, longitude: locationHandler.lhLongitude), latitudinalMeters: defaultSpan, longitudinalMeters: defaultSpan), animated: true)
            // MARK: Debug
            print(#function)
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause was determined to be improper use of passing the state of the `MKCoordinateRegion`. Every time the user submitted a search, it was firing but reloading a child view that then changed the state.